# zendframework with jquery UI datepicker getting future date 2019 instead of 2013

Tags: zend-framework

I get future date instead of 2013
below is the code

```
protected function _initView()
    {
        $view = new Zend_View();
        $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
        $view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8');
        $view->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ');
        //$view->headTitle('IMR - BI System');
        $view->env = APPLICATION_ENV;
        //$view->baseUrl = Zend_Registry::get('config')->root_path;
        $view->addHelperPath("ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper", "ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper");
//      $view->jQuery()->addStylesheet($view->baseUrl . '/js/themes/base/demos.css');
        $view->jQuery()->addStylesheet($view->baseUrl . '/js/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css');
        $view->jQuery()->addStylesheet($view->baseUrl . '/js/css/jquery.ui.theme.css');
        $view->jQuery()->setLocalPath($view->baseUrl . '/js/jquery.min.js');
        $view->jQuery()->setUiLocalPath($view->baseUrl .'/js/jquery-ui.min.js');
        $view->jQuery()->enable();
        $view->jQuery()->uiEnable();
        $viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();
        $viewRenderer->setView($view);
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);

        return $view;
    }
```

In the view i gave

```
Pick your Date: <?php echo $this->datePicker("dp1", '', array('defaultDate' => date('Y/m/d', time()))); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply not using the defaultDate parameter? It shoult default to the current date anyway. I have seen the same behaviour using defaultDate, but its fine if you dont use it.
try setting the format instead: 
    'dateFormat' => 'dd-mm-yy'